# Proving continuity using extreme value theorem

Tags: functions

> 1. Define $f$ on $[0, 4]$ by $f(x) = x + 1$ for $0 \leq x < 2$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $2 \leq x \leq 4$. Use the extreme value theorem to show that $f$ is not continuous.

Every continuous real-valued function on a closed and bounded interval in $\mathbb R$ achieves its (global) maximum and the minimum value at some points in the interval.

The function doesn't attain its global maximum.

> 2. Give an example of a function defined on $[0, 1]$ which has no maximum and no minimum on the interval. Explain why the existence of such a function does not contradict the extreme value theorem.

$f(x) = x+2$ for $[0,\frac{1}{2})$; $f(x)=\frac{3}{2}$ for $[\frac{1}{2}] $; $f(x)=x$ for $(\frac{1}{2},1]$

> 3. Give an example of a continuous function defined on the interval $(1, 2]$ which does not achieve a maximum value on the interval. Explain why the existence of such a function does not contradict the extreme value theorem.

$f(x)=-x$, Upper bounded.

> 4. Give an example of a continuous function on the closed interval $[3,4)$ which does not achieve a minimum value on the interval. Explain why the existence of such a function does not contradict the extreme value theorem.

$f(x)=-x$, Lower-bounded.

> 5. Let $f(x) =\frac{1}{x}$ for $0 < x \leq 1$ and $f(0) = 0$. Use the extreme value theorem to show that $f $is not continuous on $[0, 1]$.

Global maximum is not achieved by the function.

Can somebody please check the answers? This is my first time dealing with proof regarding functions and I am not sure if I am handling the terminology and the notations correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt for $(1)$ is half-correct.

You proved, correctly, that $f$ is not continuous, but you did not do it **using the extreme value theorem**.

Remember, the extreme value theorem states:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ reaches its maximum on $[a,b]$.

You can use this theorem to show that if $f$ does not reach its maximum, then it is not continuous. This is, in fact, what the question wants you to do.

---

For $2,3,4$:

The function $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ reaches it's maximum at $x=1$, so the example is not correct.

The function $f(x)=x$ on $(1,2]$ reaches it's maximum at $x=2$, so the example is not correct.

The function $f(x)=x$ on $[3,4)$ reaches it's minumum at $x=3$, so the example is not correct.

---

For $5$, again, you did not use the extreme value theorem.

***After your edit***:

**1**.

Your argument seems correct, however since this is mathematics, statements need proof. So, you need to actually *prove* that $f$ does not have a maximum.

**2**.

In *1*, you already say one example of a function that has no maximum on an interval. Use that to construct a function with no maximum on $[0,\frac12]$, then construct a similar function, just with no minimum, on $[\frac12, 1]$ and glue the two together.

**3**.

$f(x)=-x$ may be the correct answer, but your argument is incorrect. In fact, $f$ **is** upper bounded on $(1,2]$ because $-1$ is an upper bound for $f$.

**4**.

$f(x)=-x$ may be the correct answer, but your argument is incorrect. In fact, $f$ **is** lower bounded on $[3,4)$ because $-4$ is a lower bound for $f$.

**5**.

Incorrect argument, because the function does not even have a global maximum.

Comment: Oh I get it, I assumed a global minimum or maximum has to be a turning point. So for 1. The function doesn't have a minimum. 2. $f(x)=a$ where $a$ is a constant. Reason: Unbounded. 3. $f(x)=-x$ Reason: Unbounded. 4.$f(x)=-x$ Reason: Unbounded. 5. No maximum. Can you please check this?

Comment: @FaiqRaees please edit your original question with the new attempts, and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: @FaiqRaees I did, and I wrote the things that are wrong with your arguments.

Comment: That's what I stated for 5. The function doesn't attain its global maximum hence it is not continuous.

Comment: @FaiqRaees Oh ok. But you still have to prove that.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @FaiqRaees Example of what?

Comment: Example of how to provide a mathematical proof for discontinuity using extreme value theorem.

Comment: Please see the edit for 2. Moreover I used the intervals $[0,\frac{1}{2} )\cup[\frac{1}{2}]\cup(\frac{1}{2},1]$ whereas you suggested to use $[0,\frac{1}{2} ]\cup[\frac{1}{2},1]$. I cannot work out how can there be no minimum or maximum with closed intervals (as per your suggestion). Can you please provide an example for that too?